# Highcharts X-Axis time from JS date

Tags: javascript, date, time, highcharts, formatting

I want to visualize the temperature from my database with Highcharts.
The JS data array looks like the following:

```
[date object, value]
```

For example:

```
[Fri Mar 04 2016 01:39:10 GMT+0100 (Central Europe Standard Time), 20.5]
```

As you can see, I have a date object and a value. So my problem is to format the x-axis that it shows my dates, in best case formatted to HH:MM. It seems like I have use the xAxis type datetime, but this doesn't work.

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
    // ...
}
```

Do you know a solution for this problem?

[image: Image of graph]

Comment: Can you post the code? we need to see the chart attempt to know what to fix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Highcharts takes in `datetime` in the form of timestamps in milliseconds. You are providing a Date object. Instead of just inserting the Date object use the `getTime()` function of the Date object to get the timestamp.

For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ondkloss/nk6v2j8t/)):

```
$(function () {
    // The timestamp of the current time
    var timestampNow = new Date().getTime();
    // The timestamp one hour from now
    var timestampOneHour = new Date(timestampNow + (3600 * 1000)).getTime();

    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        series: [{
            data: [
                [timestampNow, 1],
                [timestampOneHour, 2]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: ty so much for your fast help :)